# How to print from sites that normally require OS X or Windows?

Tags: printing

I have been trying to get the Target (retail store) website to print coupons. When I click print, it tells me it does not recognize my operating system and I need Mac OS X or Windows.

How do I get these sites to work?

Comment: You might want to ask Target themselves (I am not saying that some member of the community doesn't have the solution, though).

Comment: I know this is an old post, but Coupons.com has changed their website. It now works with Linux. It treats it like a mobile device, and sends you a code that you must enter, in order to print.

Answer (score 0):

According to Coupons.com Incorporated, Customer Support, which I think they're one of the largest coupon outfits, "Unfortunately, Linux is not currently a supported platform for coupons from Coupons.com."

Now that being said, I would recommend the you install Windows inside a Virtual Machine if you really want to print these coupons.  You can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), since its free.

Comment: thanks, was really wanting to get away from windows ( bill gates you crook, lol ). I guess i still need him, huh.

Answer (score 0):

Try an extension for the browser that allows you to change the user agent. This is to make you believe the server that uses Windows. Usually this solves the problem https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg    https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/